# How to analyze compression options for Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, compression

What is the most efficient way to determine whether row or page or columnstore compression (or none) would be most effective for each index in an Azure SQL Database (standard or premium tier) used for OLTP, where **sp_estimate_data_compression_savings** is not supported?

I realize that whether doing so is good for performance would depend on the frequency and volume of writes for each index. What other considerations should be taken into account?

(I realize that whether to use columnstore for a partitioned index is a complex issue and I'll consider that out of scope for this request.)

Answer (score 5):

Kalen Delaney has created a version of `sp_estimate_data_compression_savings` specifically for this use case.

Its available for download from the corresponding blog post [here](https://www.sqlserverinternals.com/blog/2018/6/6/creating-my-own-spestimatedatacompressionsavings).

Comment: Thanks! It seems odd that a Google search for the sp name and "Azure SQL Database" wasn't turning up that blog post, but now it turns up this StackExchange page that has the pointer to Kalen's post. Oh well, at least it is more easily found now.

For anyone interested in this, please upvote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32897869-add-sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-to-sql-az

Comment: Looks like the link is dead